# I18n/L10n of an API targeting developers from maximum locales

Tags: java, api, rest, internationalization

I am already aware about the best practices for internationalizing/localizing an *application* so that it is consumable by maximum number of users - from geography, language and locale perspective. My question is - what are the (additional ?) best practices I need to follow if I want to make it easy for **developers** from across the world to consume my **API**?

I realize this question is very broad - so I will attempt to reduce the scope: I am particularly interested in creating a REST API and a Java client library for the aforementioned REST API.

Some of the things that come to mind are:

1. Provide a way for the developer to localize Strings (obvious)
2. Provide a way for the developer to customize locale-specific artifacts (measurements, units like currency, distance, weights etc)
3. Internationalize the API documentation (?? - is this done often? Is it practical?)

Beyond these measures, there are other aspects that really confuse me.

### Correctness versus Simplicity:

Should I really name my classes to reflect the technical concepts on which they are based? For example, many of the design patterns may make sense to people who are well versed in English, but for developers with a different medium of instruction, they might be difficult to grasp. So, should I, in the interest of simplicity, rename `DelegationInterceptor` to something using simpler language? I'm wondering whether this simplification might have any (legal ??) consequences ?

### Being Culture-Neutral:

Many-a-times, the easiest way for a developer to understand things is to see an example (or even a framework name) that is similar to something they see every day - which is why Pizzeria or Token Rings would be cool as example usages of my API. On the other hand, these same concepts may not be heard of in a country where most of the developers who develop to your API come from. So should I make generic examples? But then, what good are dull, boring, "generic" examples?

---

It'd be great if anyone could point me to any API's out there which do a good job of catering to developers from varied locales and cultures - not necessarily in the REST or Java space - anything will do.

Comment: Since this question is closed, I am considering moving it (and the answer by Paweł Dyda) to Community Wiki. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

My 3 cents: i18n best practices are not restricted to "geography, language and locale perspective". I even think that the most interesting aspect of i18n is getting to know and understand different **cultures** with all their richness.

To answer your question shortly: there is a book on API design written by Krzysztof Cwalina (nice first name, isn't it?) and Brad Abrams called [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613). There is also [some presentation on slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/brada/framework-design-guidelines-presentation).
Anyway, I read the book and I think it is great, eye opening at least.

The longer answer... What you are referring to, is a Programming Usability. I haven't actually seen the topic covered in details (yet), but you can find many articles on Usability of Programming Languages (i.e. [these slides](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011//R201/UPLslidesV7-printversion.pdf)). It seems this is pretty new discipline and the one that is pretty hard (it is a mixture of psychology, linguistics, grammar in two different sense, theory behind compilers, algorithmic, ... , and **more**). The most important would be of course human factor, especially inherent ability to produce errors.
Very interesting topic :)

Going through details of your question:

1. There is no way to create L10n API, as Localization is a process of adapting the software to *local* market needs. What you want to create is ***i18n-related*** API.
2. I don't necessary know why it has to be REST API, but to be 100% honest I am afraid that you might want to create some super-fantastic API that is actually **against** i18n best practices. The first things first: if you want it to be consumed by many developers, it should be regular API just like ICU. Maybe some parts of it could be exposed as RESTful API, but I am not sure ***why*** you want to do this.
3. As I already mentioned, there is something called [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), especially [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/). I know that this API is extremely complex and not very developer-friendly, but it has one very important advantage: it does exist. And it was created by i18n experts, so it ***really*** follows best practices. Some parts are inherently complex because of nature of things - they just have to be if you want to implement the cultural support correctly. Sorry.
4. By the way: I might be wrong, but you said REST API, which rings a bell in my head. I believe you think of i18n support on the client side, don't you? In such case, I must ask one question: what is wrong with [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) and/or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and why you think it is better option to do everything on the server side?
   OK, with Dojo I can answer the question myself: size and responsiveness.
5. Going through your points: "Provide a way for the developer to localize Strings (obvious)". It is not so obvious. That is, it is not as easy as you might think. If you want to do the obvious, you must be sure to understand the terms: Resource Model, Resource Organization, Locale Fall-back, Message Formatting, Machine Translation and Translation Memory.
   Trust me, it is really easy to do a mistake here. On one hand, I doubt that anyone could create an API that will stop regular programmers from being lazy and hardcode strings, I doubt that it will ever happen. On the other hand, your friendly API (if you could achieve this) could easily allow reusing translations (which is i18n defect if it doesn't regard to common things like "OK", "Cancel", etc.). Also, you need to think of formatting capability so that it is (almost) impossible to introduce concatenations (very common i18n defect, preventing correct translations) and at the same time it is easy to handle multiple plural forms (still think you know best practices...?).
   Proper organization and valid abstract model might help with implementation of TM and MT (that is reusing of old translations and minimizing the costs of new ones). But this is hard and very few people do it correctly (there are even some frameworks, like [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) for example that implement serious misconceptions, i.e. single translation file only).
6. "Provide a way for the developer to customize locale-specific artifacts (measurements, units like currency, distance, weights etc)". Great idea. But please make sure that you will include formats as well. I mean that number format varies, unit varies, unit name and symbols (even for the same units) varies, but also **unit placement** may vary.
   Some of these artifacts are already in ICU and [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/index), but for others you would actually need to get valid translations of patterns and items themselves.
   From my experience it might be hard to collect the translations in the first place, yet valid ones...
7. "Internationalize the API documentation". Let me guess: you meant ***Localize***, which in that case would probably be equal to *Translate*.
   To be honest, I don't think that translating documentation of some API or Framework is all that important. Professional programmers have to have some command of English, at least be able to understand the technical documentation and write passable code (in terms of variable names and comments) - it is ***very unprofessional*** not to use English for such items.
8. "Correctness vs. Simplicity". I am not sure what kind of correctness you refer to. In terms of English language grammar, I would definitely favor simplicity over language correctness.
   In terms of valid support for i18n, there are so many incorrect libraries already, please refrain from providing another one. As I wrote before, some things are inherently complex and they could be either done correctly (that will result in a complex API) or should not be done at all. Bringing simple, but only partially correct solution for cultural support will result in large number of defects (that I will curse you for) and the need to find even more complex workarounds. It is not worth the effort.
9. "Being culture neutral". Please read the book, I recommended. It covers this shortly (there is no need to go deeper, actually).
   I doubt you should actually strive so much for political correctness, just avoid something you are sure my hurt somebody's feelings (don't do to others what you don't want to do unto you). That's it.

---

EDIT: Just two more things.

10. It might be a good idea to actually perform Usability tests on your API (just like you would do for User Interface). If it feels natural and intuitive, you did a great job. By doing that, you will also learn how people might want to use your library, that is you will discover additional use cases.
11. It is probably much harder to create programming library than to actually create a program. In case of library/API you often need to break truths that are (or at least seem to be) carved into stone, that is create something that is against common OOP/OOD principles, but is easy to use. You would also need to provide more overloads (there are many different use cases, mind you). Something as simple as formatting Date/Time in Java could really give you a headache if you want to support java.util.Date, Calendar, java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp, XMLGregorianCalendar, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and [JSR-310](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen).

As a side not, I am not sure if sending formatted date/times over REST API is actually the i18n best practice...

Comment: Wow - that was detailed! I will need to go over this time and again to fully understand everything. One point though - the real agenda was indeed to make the API suitable for different cultures. I might have wrongly clubbed the terms I18n and L10n - but you get the idea.

Comment: re: Dojo size and responsiveness, are you familiar with the deployment tools for Dojo?

Comment: @peller: I am certainly not, so if you can point me to docs that contradicts my theory, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/i18n/  All resource bundles for a particuilar locale used on a page can be combined into a single file, or a single HTTP hit to retrieve them, similar to how the tool concatenates Javascript and CSS.  From that point, you're just accessing properties on an object in the browser.    The build tools were replaced with AMD-aware build tools in v1.7+ which will achieve similar results.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question has been closed. I have requested for reopening. In the meanwhile, I went through the various links your provided, and while they are all very informative; I did not find anything concrete. You have got my upvote for the detailed responses but I've stopped short of accepting the answer.